# Using CSS, how can I change the alignment of a click-to-open UL menu?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I've the following very basic menu bar on the top of my page:

[image: both menus closed]

The left "hamburger" menu opens aligned to the left, with the width expanding toward the right. All is well:

[image]

However, the right one also aligns to the left, with the width expanding toward the right. This isn't so great:

[image]

How would I go about making that right menu rest against the right edge, in the same way the left menu rests against the left edge?

My html is below. The css is somewhat long (therefore, [here's a paste link](https://paste.kde.org/pknrjbltv)) but simple.

```html
<div id='header'>
    <div id='headerContent'>
        <div id='breadcrumbs'>
            <div id='hamburger' class='headerMenu'>
                <i class='fa fa-bars'></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='/'>Page</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/'>Whatever</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/'>Other stuff</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div> Title
        </div>
        <div id='login'>
            <div class='headerMenu'>
                <i class='fa fa-user-circle'></i>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='/user/logout/'>Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like having a container to hold the button and menu with `position: relative` and setting `text-align: right`, then using `right: 0` on the menu would be the right way to go:

```css
#header {
  background: lightblue;
}
.right {
  text-align: right;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
}
.popup {
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="right">
    <a>Menu</a>
    <ul class="popup">
      Popup menu
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should be able to modify the container div in many ways (e.g. width, margin, `display: inline-block`, etc) without messing up the behavior.

Comment: Bingo! Specifically `position:relative` and `right:0` were what I needed.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you don't need text-align unless you want to right-align the text...